# Vagrant up on windows 8 with puphpet error

Tags: windows, vagrant, puphpet

I'm having this error on a windows 8, latest versions of vagrant 1.7.4 and virtualbox 5.0.10 installed:

```
D:\myproject>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: base
    default:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /myproject/base
```

It seems like the path is invalid, this is windows but the path seems to be a linux system.

Same thing happen if I do

```
 vagrant init
 vagrant up
```

In a new folder.

This download the box succesfully:

```
 vagrant box add puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
```

Comment: Can you post your Vagrantfile please, might be something to do with the paths in there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be modify vagrantfile.You have to make your own name instead of the base package or you should run it first vagrant init {boxname}